# GDPR and HTTP requests

Tags: gdpr, popi

A person A makes an app and publishes it to play store. The app requests a page from a server not under his control as a part of the app . The users ip address is transmitted and logged in the servers logs and the data controller meaning the app developer has know that he has no control on it .Recieves a request from an user to delete ip logs under GDPR . What must the person do?
GDPR states that as the data controller he must delete server logs but he cannot. The server talked about here is time.google.com.

Comment: Add a comment if any more clarification is needed .

Comment: Will respond as soon as comment is seen.

Comment: You are drastically simplifying what the GDPR requires - multiple entities can be both "Data Controller" and "Data Processor" or one or the other.  You need to work out in your example who is acting as which, because it changes the outcome and what actions are needed to be taken.

Comment: Can you explain further. Take an app asking time from time.google.com and google logging the ip as example.

Comment: Who is a "Data Controller" and "Data Processor" depends on who can do what - if you are calling time.google.com with no specific contractual relationship between you and Google, then Google is both "Data Controller" and "Data Processor" for that data, and you need to make your users aware of that.  If you are storing data in Azure for example, you would be the "Data Controller" and probably the "Data Processor", but Microsoft Azure would probably also be a "Data Processor" depending on what features you use.  So you need to identify the roles everyone plays, and make the user aware.

Comment: I am just sending a request to obtain date from google and I will TAKE USER CONSENT for doing so explicitly.

Comment: No contract signed with google.

Comment: Might add a clause to terms of use stating these requests will be considered as if user made those out of his own will.

Comment: Why do you think you have to comply with the erasure request? There are plenty of GDPR compliant reasons why you don’t. Maybe you need to read the regulation https://gdpr-info.eu

Comment: Can you please just tell which article will protect me against such Erasure request?

Answer (score 0):

Art. 17 GDPR Right to erasure (‘right to be forgotten’) can be found [here](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/). I could not find an article which would easily protect you in the scenario, but I would by happy if somebody could share such information.

I think a technical solution for your scenario would be e.g. if your app visits the external link via an application server which is under your control. By doing so the external server only logs your server's IP address, and only you log the App's IP address which is now under your full control.

This relates to "Deep-Linking" and there are discussions (e.g. in Germany) if this is legal or not, especially concerning copyright or if you use this technique to circumvent access to the external webpage. One [blog in German](https://www.suchmaschinen-und-recht.de/aufsaetze/deep-linking-nun-doch-verboten/#:%7E:text=Seit%20der%20%22Paperboy%22%2DEntscheidung,Deep%2DLinkings%20ganz%20erheblich%20ein.) says (Google translation):

> Deep-linking banned after all? Since the "Paperboy" decision of the
> Federal Court of Justice (BGH) in 2003, it has been known that deep
> linking is generally permitted. Now the Karlsruhe judges have recently
> issued a new judgment and thereby considerably restrict the
> possibility of deep linking. After that, it is sufficient for the site
> operator to be linked to use session IDs to classify a deep link as a
> copyright infringement.

More about legal issues with deep linking are summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking#Court_rulings).

Another possible solution would be to start the web browser on your phone via your app and let it handle the visit to the external webpage. But this is maybe not the user experience which you had in mind with your app.

Comment: Yeah that is deffinitely a solution(first one you proposed) the only thing is GDPR is imposing many requirements that is making owning a server compulsory.By the way if a provide a link to the site and keep a button for the user to press instead of auto.

Comment: That would probably bypass gdpr as user would be data controller.

Comment: I am not sure if such a button would bypass GDPR, but I would appreciate it if someone can comment on this. I think in this case you would operate like a browser.